# HTTP Get method based on parameters in java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement a class that gets data from mysql via my web service. I have previously used a http post to get information from a table but this time I intend a user to input a string into an editText, press search and the textview to display the query.For example, Imagine there are two columns of the mysql table: Firstname and surname; I would like to be able to get the surname by searching the Firstname (Entering the Firstname into the EditText and displaying the surname of that person).I have developed the PHP script but is it possible to use the HTTP get method based on an input string? how? I've only seen tutorials directing straight to the php link

Comment: why dont you want to use post for that?

Comment: I would use post if I was to edit the table but i only want to get the information for the table based on the parameter. basically the input of the editText will be entered into a mysql query: SELECT Firstname FROM People WHERE Firstname = "the string entered into the EditText"

Comment: yea well the same can be achieved using HttpPost and it would for sure provide a more secure option. you can still use get if you dont want to go for post. i could post some code for that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a example how you could do it by using NameValuePairs which you can pass to the php file using a post request.

```
private void sendData(ArrayList<NameValuePair> data)
{
     // 1) Connect via HTTP. 2) Encode data. 3) Send data.
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new      
        HttpPost("http://www.blah.com/AddAccelerationData.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
            //Could do something better with response.
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
    }  
}
```

Now lets say you want to use this method to pass info(i.e. your parameter to the php file.

```
  //Add data to be send.
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parameter",editTextValue));
    this.sendData(nameValuePairs);
```

Now on the php side of things you can then get this parameter value by calling:

```
 //Retrieve the data.
 $parameter = $_POST['parameter'];
 //Now call on your query or function or w/e it is using this parameter.
```

Answer (score 1):

To use GET, simply encode the values into your URL, e.g.

```
String url = "http://myserver.net/script.php?first=" + URLEncoder.encode(first) +
             "&last=" + URLEncoder.encode(last);
```

And then use an HttpGet object with your HttpClient:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(url));
```

Processing the response is then the same as if you had posted it.